# SQL Server database architecture (design) + reporting for deleted objects

Tags: sql-server, database, architecture

I'd like to handle entries for reporting purposes even if the entries are deleted.

For example (simple scenario), I have two tables:

1. Administrators
2. AdministratorActions

If administrator do something, it will be saved into the `AdministratorActions` table. It should be possible to delete some administrators (entries) from `Administrators` table.

But when we delete (real deletion) some admins from the table, we aren't able to track the actions in `AdministratorActions` back to a deleted name.

The simplest solution for that is: just add a column `IsDeleted` in the `Administrators` table and don't actually delete the entries. But I think, that's a really really ugly DB design.

Are there any other good solutions for doing that a nice way?

The background is: we have to report all the done actions and should be able to track the actions back to the initiator (Administrator name of table `Administrators`.

I'm very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's ugly at all.

If you want to physically DELETE the Administrators record, then you will not be able to create a FOREIGN KEY constraint from AdministratorActions - that, IMHO, is a far worse situation.

It's perfectly common to have some form of IsDeleted/Status flag against a record to maintain referential integrity and this ensures you can benefit from FK constraints.

An alternative would be to also store the data for an administrator in the AdministratorActions table, instead of linking via the id. However, you should ask yourself if you really want that level of data duplication.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your fast answer. I think I will use the flag scenario. But I can't believe that Microsoft are using such a flag for their real big products like Forefront Identity Manager (FIM) which has implemented nice reporting features.

Answer (score 1):

You can denormalize your `AdministratorActions` table and the `AdministratorName` column to it.

Comment: That's another possible solution. But the two tables above are just an example, in real it is a complex DB design with a lot of tables. So, the DB size will grow/size up enorm.

Comment: If this is the case, I agree with @AdaTheDev's answer.  You would be better off using the status flag.